# how to pass data from one activity to another activity with th use of Application class

Tags: android, android-intent

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyData extends Application{
private String name;
private String phone;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

When I am using following line of code in caller Activity to send data, I get a ClassCastException:

```
MyData data=(MyData)getApplication();
```

Comment: any specific reason for extending application class,
have u tried data=new MyData();

Comment: Have you declared your application as "MyData" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the extended Application name to your manifest: `<application ... android:name="MyData">...</application`. [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

or

https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=extending%20application%20android&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a1bc1589ec616832&biw=1680&bih=925&pf=p&pdl=500

Those two might help you. Personally, I don't know the answer, but the top link appears pretty helpful.